# C# WebClient.DownloadString doesn't return whole webpage source

Tags: c#, html, webclient

I am using `WebClient.DownloadString` to get the Html source of a webpage, but all I get as a return is:

```html
<html style="height:100%">
<head>
    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
</head>

<body style="margin:0px;height:100%">
    <iframe id="main-iframe"
        src="/_Incapsula_Resource?CWUDNSAI=41&xinfo=9-19309783-0%20NNNY%20RT%281614802895891%2028%29%20q%280%20-1%20-1%20-1%29%20r%280%20-1%29%20B10%2814%2c0%2c0%29%20U18&incident_id=1309000160050658955-81390253115245577&edet=10&cinfo=0e000000b6ef&rpinfo=0"
        frameborder=0 width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">
        Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 1309000160050658955-81390253115245577
    </iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

But the actual content of the page is missing. What have I done wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "actual content"? That's looks pretty much like a full html to me.

Comment: I suppose you expected it to load the iframe, no it won't do that. It just downloads whatever string it's given, it doesn't parse any HTML and it's not an internet browser

Comment: Incapsula is an anti-ddos service like cloudflare. Looks like it's doing as it's supposed to, which is effectively working out that your app isn't a browser used by a human and it's telling you to go away! How badly do you want to solve this? To what ends will you go to defeat Incapsula?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTTP request does not satisfy the requirements of the server, so Incapsula has flagged you as a suspicious user. The response you posted does contain the complete web response text. I would look into making sure you are supplying enough information in the request.

Some things to check to add to your HTTP request are the headers like user agent, cookies, etc.